# Ajax form won't post in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following code works great in FF and Chrome: The form is posted via Ajax and the modal window appears. In IE9, the modal window appears but the form is not posted.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#thanks').modal();
});

$('.ajaxform').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function () { }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.example.com/post.php" class="ajaxform">
<label>First name*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" required>

                    <label>Last name*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" required>

                    <label>Email address*</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" required>

                    <label>Phone number*</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" required>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Request" role="button" href="#thanks">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on these `inputs etc.`?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Edit to include some sample inputs. Console doesn't show any type of errors in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check whether your submit event handler is actually being called in IE? Reason I'm asking is that the jQuery *.submit()* documentation states that:

> "The JavaScript submit event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. However, scripts that rely on event delegation with the submit event will work consistently across browsers as of jQuery 1.4, which has normalized the event's behavior."

So depending on the jQuery version you are using, this might be an issue...
Also, using Fiddler or the console to check whether the Ajax call is actually leaving the browser might give a hint.

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply -- I believe this was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your ajax call makes this into an actual post.  If it's a get, you may have to disable caching in IE.  The jQuery ajax call has a setting for that: `cache: false`.

```
$('.ajaxform').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function () { }
    });
    return false;
});
```